# Quando uso ObjectOutputStream os atributos da classe pai também são gravados?

Tags: java, arquivo

Quando uso o [`ObjectOutpuStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) para gravar em arquivo, os atributos da classe pai também serão gravados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, não só os atributos do objeto em si são salvos, mas também os das superclasses, e também **todos os objetos referenciados**. Ou seja, é gravado um "grafo" de objetos suficiente para restaurar o objeto salvo por completo, sem depender de nenhum objeto pré-existente.

Exemplo:

```
class A {
    int x;
}

class B {
    A y;
}

class C extends B {
    int z;
}
```

Ao serializar um objeto de `C`, serão incluídos os campos `y` e `z`, sendo que `y` será uma serialização do objeto da classe `A` (ou seja, `x` também será incluído).

Nota: esse exemplo está simplificado. De acordo com [a documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) do `ObjectOutputStream`, somente objetos que implementam a interface [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) serão escritos no arquivo. Se a memória não me falha, qualquer objeto não serializável no grafo de objetos fará com que uma exceção seja lançada ao se tentar a serialização - a menos que exista código próprio para tratar desse caso.

Comment: Acho que é prudente citar que não são **todos** os objetos referenciados que são serializados -- fields marcados com `transient` não são serializados.

Answer (score 3):

Tratando-se de herança, existem algumas nuances quanto ao que será ou não incluído na serialização.

O `ObjectOutputStream` irá serializar todas as classes da hierarquia que são marcados com `java.io.Serializable` e seus descendentes. Desses, os atributos não estáticos, não transientes e que também são marcados com a referida interface serão serializados.

Meio complicado, não? Vamos ver um...

## Exemplo prático (com erro)

Primeiro, duas classes que serão referenciadas, uma serializável e outra não:

```java
class OutraClasseSerializavel implements Serializable {
    int outroValorSerializavel;
}

class OutraClasse {
    int outroValor;
}
```

Segundo, uma classe "pai" e uma "filha":

```java
class Pai {
    OutraClasse outraClassePai;
    OutraClasseSerializavel outraClasseSerializavelPai;
    int valorPai;
}

class Filha extends Pai implements Serializable {
    OutraClasse outraClasseFilha;
    OutraClasseSerializavel outraClasseSerializavelFilha;        
    int valorFilha;
}
```

Note que as duas classes possuem valores e referências para classes serializáveis e não serializáveis.

O que acontece se tentarmos serializar a classe `Filha`? Ocorre um `java.io.NotSerializableException` por causa da referência à classe não serializável `OutraClasse` na classe `Filha`.

## Exemplo prático

Se removermos a referência à classe não serializável da classe `Filha`, o erro não ocorre:

```java
class Filha extends Pai implements Serializable {
    OutraClasseSerializavel outraClasseSerializavelFilha;        
    int valorFilha;
}
```

## Testando e analisando o resultado

Vamos fazer um teste:

```java
Filha filha = new Filha();

//valores da classe filha
filha.valorFilha = 11;
filha.outraClasseSerializavelFilha = new OutraClasseSerializavel();
filha.outraClasseSerializavelFilha.outroValorSerializavel = 33;

//valores da classe pai
filha.valorPai = 22;
filha.outraClasseSerializavelPai = new OutraClasseSerializavel();
filha.outraClasseSerializavelPai.outroValorSerializavel = 44;
filha.outraClassePai = new OutraClasse();
filha.outraClassePai.outroValor = 55;

//serializa
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("filha.out")));
oos.writeObject(filha);
oos.close();

//recupera classe serializada
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("filha.out")));
Filha filhaRecuperada = (Filha) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Finalmente, vamos imprimir e analisar os valores retornados...

### Atributo primitivo na classe serializável

```java
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.valorFilha);
```

Saída:

> 11

Obviamente, o atributo `valorFilha` é devidamente serializado e recuperado porque faz parte da classe serializável e é um tipo primitivo.

### Referência à classe serializável em uma classe também serializável

```java
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClasseSerializavelFilha.outroValorSerializavel);
```

Saída:

> 33

O atributo `outraClasseSerializavelFilha` também foi serializado corretamente, assim como seu valor, porque é uma referência a uma classe serializável a partir da classe `Filha` que é serializável.

### Atributo primitivo na classe `Pai`, que não é serializável

```java
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.valorPai);
```

Saída:

> 0

Observamos agora que, embora não ocorram erros, atributos estáticos em uma superclasse não serializável não são serializados.

### Referência à classes serializáveis e não serializáveis em uma superclasse não serializável

```java
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClassePai);
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClasseSerializavelPai);
```

Saída:

> null
>
> null

E, finalmente, observamos que referências a classes de qualquer tipo (serializáveis ou não) em uma superclasse não serializável também serão excluídas da serialização.

## Considerações

Estender uma classe para torná-la serializável não funciona, pois como foi visto o processo de serialização ignora as superclasses não serializáveis e um erro ocorre ao incluirmos um atributo não serializável.

**Mas existe alguma solução? A resposta é sim!**

## Solução: readObject e writeObject

A [documentação da classe `java.io.Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) aponta alguns métodos que devem ser implementados para que você possa alterar "manualmente" a forma como o Java serializa e desserializa um objeto.

As assinaturas são:

```java
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
```

### Exemplo de implementação

Segue uma implementação básica dos métodos `readObject()` e `writeObject()` na classe Filha que resolvem o problema da serialização tanto do atributo inteiro da superclasse quanto das referências a outros objetos:

```java
class Filha extends Pai implements Serializable {
    
    int valorFilha;
    transient OutraClasse outraClasseFilha;
    OutraClasseSerializavel outraClasseSerializavelFilha;
    
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        valorFilha =  stream.readInt();
        outraClasseFilha = new OutraClasse();
        outraClasseFilha.outroValor = stream.readInt();
        outraClasseSerializavelFilha = (OutraClasseSerializavel) stream.readObject();
        
        valorPai = stream.readInt();
        outraClassePai = new OutraClasse();
        outraClassePai.outroValor = stream.readInt();
        outraClasseSerializavelPai = (OutraClasseSerializavel) stream.readObject();
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
            throws IOException {
        stream.writeInt(valorFilha);
        stream.writeInt(outraClasseFilha.outroValor);
        stream.writeObject(outraClasseSerializavelFilha);
        
        stream.writeInt(valorPai);
        stream.writeInt(outraClassePai.outroValor);
        stream.writeObject(outraClasseSerializavelPai);
    }
    
}
```

Então fazemos um novo teste:

```java
Filha filha = new Filha();

//valores da classe filha
filha.valorFilha = 11;
filha.outraClasseSerializavelFilha = new OutraClasseSerializavel();
filha.outraClasseSerializavelFilha.outroValorSerializavel = 22;
filha.outraClasseFilha = new OutraClasse();
filha.outraClasseFilha.outroValor = 33;

//valores da classe pai
filha.valorPai = 44;
filha.outraClasseSerializavelPai = new OutraClasseSerializavel();
filha.outraClasseSerializavelPai.outroValorSerializavel = 55;
filha.outraClassePai = new OutraClasse();
filha.outraClassePai.outroValor = 66;

//serializa
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("c.out")));
oos.writeObject(filha);
oos.close();

//recupera classe serializada
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("c.out")));
Filha filhaRecuperada = (Filha) ois.readObject();
ois.close();

//valores da classe filha
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.valorFilha);
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClasseSerializavelFilha.outroValorSerializavel);
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClasseFilha.outroValor);

//valores da classe pai
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.valorPai);
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClasseSerializavelPai.outroValorSerializavel);
System.out.println(filhaRecuperada.outraClassePai.outroValor);
```

E obtemos a saída:

```java
11
22
33
44
55
66
```

**Todos os atributos foram salvos!**

## Conclusão

Embora o Java não resolva toda a questão da serialização *automagicamente*, ele nos fornece um mecanismo prático e flexível para resolver isso, pois permite controlar completamente como o objeto é salvo e recuperado do arquivo.

Por outro lado, é exigido codificação manual de cada atributo da classe, na ordem correta.